# Getting every possible itteration of sorting m items into n containers - Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a probability calculator and I need to solve the following problem: how to I get every unique instance of sorting m indistinct items into n indistinct containers?

Example:
I have 4 objects and 3 containers. The unique ways of sorting this are:
(4, 0, 0), (3, 1, 0), (2, 2, 0), (2, 1, 1).

Solutions such as (0, 4, 0) must be discounted since the items and containers are indistinct and thus (0, 4, 0) is the same as (4, 0, 0) when calculating the probability.

I need to write code that takes in the number of items, m, and the number of containers, n, to then create a set of inputs to be used as arguments in calculating the probability using the following code:

```
def get_p_win(*args: tuple) -> float:
    probability_of_loss = 1
    for i in args:
        probability_of_loss *= (1-i[0] / i[1])
    return (1 - probability_of_loss) * 100
```

Example input:
`get_p_win((4, 200), (0, 200), (0, 200))`
This return the probability of getting a win from one of the 3 input draws, assuming each has 200 entries and only the first draw has 4 of our entries.

I am, however, unsure of even where to begin with this so any help will be appreciated!

### EDIT

Using the method advised by AdaPre, I got the following code working:

```
def test_strategies(entries: int, draws: int):
    l = it.combinations_with_replacement(range(entries+1), draws)
    for i in l:
        sum = 0
        for index in range(draws):
            sum += i[index]
        if sum == entries:
            print (i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using pythons `itertools`? From the given specifications method `combinations_with_replacement` should return just what you're looking for.

[Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement)

Comment: Thank you! Tweaked around with this and it's working great.